# controll rrbot from ros node instead manually

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros) tutorial how can i control the position of rrbot by sending the position commands from ros node instead manually. I also tried [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6) tutorial to control volocity of joint of velodyne sensor but i am confused how i can exactly control the robot from ROS in gazebo. Can  just make one ros publisher and than publish those same msgs from ros node doing some trajectory planning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250001/controll-rrbot-from-ros-node-instead-manually/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at my [tutorial](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control), Goal 2 - Step 3.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-12-14**:
Well i also want to subscribe to the joint states published by the rrbot inside the ros node. Can i make simple ros subscriber and than just read them? I am using c++ api.

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-12-14**:
Yeah, that will do just fine. Tutorial can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).